# Xpath: How to select 1st and 2nd number separately in a sentence

Tags: xpath, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a project where I need to parse a webpage for daily updates and print them in my spreadsheet. I am using `=importXML()`
I only need two numbers from there that are contained in one sentence(a subheader) here is an example

```
<div class="col-sm-12 text-18 line-height-27">

  <h2>Header</h2>

  <p class="text-18">
      <strong>21 some words 234 another few words</strong>
  </p> 
  <p class="text-18">
    Some content ... 
  </p>


  <h2>Header 2</h2>

  <p class="text-18">
      <strong>12 some words 144 another few words</strong>
  </p> 
  <p class="text-18">
    Some old content ... 
  </p>

  //and it goes on and on


</div>
```

I need to extract only number 21 and 234 separately, printed in each own cell where my other spreadsheet functions use them for other tables.

I can select the whole sentence easily with

```
//div/p[1]/strong
```

but after that I dunno how to break the sentence down. Is there any way to select only 1st and 2nd numbers from the sentence?
Can XPath do that? Maybe I better off break the sentence down and extract numbers by google spreadsheet formulas?

Comment: share the url and copy of your sheet

Answer (score 0):

You could easily do that with XPath-2.0's `fn:replace` function (which is not supported by Google).

To achieve that in XPath-1.0, you have to use some tricks. The following is just one approach which heavily depends on the possible values:

```
concat(substring-before(normalize-space(translate(/div/p[1]/strong,'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ,;.:-/','')),' '),' - ',substring-after(normalize-space(translate(/div/p[1]/strong,'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ,;.:-/','')),' '))
```

This approach replaces all `a..z` and `A..Z` characters (and some punctuation) by an empty character. The numbers do remain, and they are splitted with `fn:substring-before(...)` and `fn:substring-after(...)`.

This is quite complicated, and doesn't work in cases where not all characters are matched.

In this example, the output is

> 21 - 234

Answer (score 0):

This should work assuming there are only letters and numbers in the sentence.  Otherwise you will need to adjust the REGEX.  This removes all letters from a to z and is not case sensitive.

```
=split(REGEXREPLACE(IMPORTXML(url,xpath_query),"(?i)[a-z]","")," ")
```

Answer (score 0):

One liner with REGEXEXTRACT (SPLIT is not needed):

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(IMPORTXML(yourURL;"//div/p[1]/strong");"(\d+).+\s(\d+)")
```